# Multiple instances of Traefik in different kubernetes namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-ingress

We're trying to run a kubernetes cluster with three namespaces:

- `public` contains services accessible to anyone
- `internal` contains services that should only be accessed by members of staff
- `engineering` contains services that should only be visible to developers

The `internal` and `engineering` namespaces are protected with mutual authentication, each using a different certificate authority.

We're using Traefik as to manage ingresses to these services however, following the [kubernetes guide](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/) to set up Traefik, grants each instance of Traefik permissions to see ingresses across all namespaces. This means you could use a service in the `internal` namespace via the Traefik instance running in the `public` namespace, bypassing the mututal authentication.

We're working around this by setting hosts on the ingresses, but this means ingresses must be defined seperately for each environment (eg, `host: engineering.example.com` is different to `host: engineering.staging.example.com`). We'd prefer to leave the host out of the ingress configuration.

In theory, using RBAC we, should be able to restrict what Traefik is allowed to see to just resources in it's own ingresses as suggested in [this guide on RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding).

My understanding is that it still needs ClusterRole permissions such as this:

```
---
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - services
      - endpoints
      - secrets
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
    resources:
      - ingresses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
```

But using a Role binding instead of a ClusterRole binding will then restrict those permissions to just the ones in the given service accounts namespace. So if the service account is in the engineering namespace:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
  namespace: engineering
```

Then the role binding would be:

```
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
  namespace: engineering
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
```

We then tie the service account to the Traefik deployment with:

```
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
  namespace: engineering
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: traefik-ingress-controller
      ...
```

We also set the namespaces in the config as per the kubernetes [configuration guide](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/kubernetes/)

```
[kubernetes]
namespaces = ["engineering"]
```

However, when Traefik starts we get the error:

`E0313 11:15:57.971237 1 reflector.go:199] github.com/containous/traefik/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache/reflector.go:94: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: endpoints is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:engineering:traefik-ingress-controller" cannot list endpoints at the cluster scope: Unknown user "system:serviceaccount:engineering:traefik-ingress-controller"`

The `Unknown user` is confusing as this is obviously binding a `ServiceAccount` not a user. Additionally, we can see the `ServiceAccount` has been created via kubectl.

I'm at a bit of a dead end here.

How do I make Traefik only pick up Ingresses in it's own namespace?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error may occur when Traefik believes that no namespaces were configured; that is, the TOML configuration you outlined

```
[kubernetes]
namespaces = ["engineering"]
```

is not becoming effective.

I can think of two reasons:

1. In addition to the TOML configuration file, you are also passing a `--kubernetes` command-line argument to Traefik (through an `args` entry in the Deployment manifest). This would disable the `namespaces` option.
2. The file is not properly mounted into the Deployment, causing the default `namespaces` value (the empty list) to be effective. To tell whether that's truly the case, we need to see your full ConfigMap and the relevant volume sections of your Deployment manifests.

Comment: Ah ok, so we did have the `--kubernetes` switch, so I pulled that, no more errors... but no logs at all, and no resposne from Traefik itself (just times out). Our GKE control panel says the app is running happily though.  Pretty sure the config is being read as it's position hasn't changed and (aside from this problem) all our MA certs, acme, etc are working correctly.

Comment: By default, Traefik only logs warnings. Increase the log level to INFO or even DEBUG to see what it does. Check the Traefik dashboard to see if frontends / backends are registered properly. Finally, do you have a Service object for Traefik that allows you to reach the Traefik pods through a NodePort, LoadBalancer, or something similar?

Comment: ‍♂️ At some point (with all the restarting and what not) our IP address had changed. Unfortunately, we're _still_ able to cross namespaces with Traefik.

Comment: Tore down the whole thing and started from scratch and it's now working. It might just be difficult to get rid of the old `ClusterRoleBinding`s (we did delete them but that didn't seem to help). Anyway, thank you! ‍♂️